# Assigning on click events to dynamic element using one

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am building a form that submits quantity dynamically.

the problem I am having is maintaining the click events on freshly loaded rows. I would like the 'one' event to be reassigned after each submission. I currently have:

```
$(this).one('click',function(e){
```

To allow for delegating new DOM elements, I think it needs to look a little like:

```
$(document).one('click',this,function(e){
```

But I can't make that work

[Here is a simplified version of the code](http://jsfiddle.net/8XLNE/)

Comment: Why not just delegate the event to the TABLE element?

Comment: No, I mean one. I want it to fire once until it is reassigned. http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: If they are stored in the same element, you could just add a single listener to the parent then use event.target to get which node was clicked

Comment: SReject, the event target is what I was looking for. Flesh it out into an answer and I can select it :)

Answer (score 0):

[`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) accepts a selector:

> .one( events [, selector] [, data], handler(eventObject) )

So, you'd change your code to something like:

```
$(document).one('click','tr',function(e){
```

Adjust accordingly.